# FTP Upload from Windows Batch File

Tags: file-upload, batch-file, ftp, windows-server-2008

Following various guides around the net, I put together a batch file that should upload a .zip to our central file server. However, If I use "ftp -n -s:ftpup.dat 108.174.61.82 20" it doesn't work with the port 20 added to the host. I have also tried "ftp -n -s:ftpup.dat" then "open 108.174.61.82 20" on the next line which also fails. What exactly am I doing wrong?

```
cd MySQL
@echo off
echo user backups>ftpup.dat
echo passwordhere>>ftpup.dat
echo cd /MySQL>>ftpup.dat
echo binary>>ftpup.dat
echo put MYSQL-%location%.%backuptime%.zip>>ftpup.dat
echo quit>>ftpup.dat
ftp -n -s:ftpup.dat serveriphere 20
del ftpup.dat
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you running FTP server or port 20?

**Telnet serveriphere 20** to check if the port is listening, maybe you have
it running on default port **21**

PS: Is it raw ftp protocol?. Maybe It is using SFTP or FTPS

**EDIT**: Try with

> ftp -s:ftpup.dat serveriphere 20

Remove the -n autologin flag

Try with this:

```
Echo ~UsrName~> ftpcmd.txt
echo ~myPass~>> ftpcmd.txt
echo binary>> ftpcmd.txt
echo prompt n>>ftpcmd.txt
echo mget *.exe>> ftpcmd.txt
echo bye >> ftpcmd.txt
ftp -s:ftpcmd.txt ~ftpAddress~
del ftpcmd.txt
```

Comment: It's definitely on port 20 which is why I must specify it.

Comment: It is raw ftp. When I manually type everything out via the command console, it works fine. It is when I add it to ftpup.dat and try and pass that file along as well as specifying a port that it fails.

Comment: Try with

ftp -s:ftpup.dat serveriphere 20

Remove the -n autologin flag

Comment: I gave it a try without the -n but same thing happened and I just received the help information for the FTP command

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question, but I had the same problem with the port, this is what worked for me, I saved the command  `open %ftphost% > ftpcmd.dat` in the file instead of calling it later

```
SET ftphost=172.xxx.xxx.xx 22    
ECHO open %ftphost% > ftpcmd.dat
ECHO user %username%>> ftpcmd.dat
ECHO %userpass%>> ftpcmd.dat
ECHO bin>> ftpcmd.dat
ECHO put %file%>> ftpcmd.dat
ECHO quit>> ftpcmd.dat

ftp -n -s:ftpcmd.dat
del ftpcmd.dat
```